# Как сделать ScrollBar со значениями (WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне нужно сделать, что то вроде такого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То, что у меня пока, что получилось сделать это вот такое

```
<ScrollBar Name="McScroller" 
                           Orientation="Horizontal"  
                           Width ="250" Height="30"  
                           Margin="10,10,0,0"  
                           Minimum="1"
                           Maximum="6"
                           Value="3"
                           Background="LightSalmon" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Осатлось 3 вопроса

1. Как пронумеровать каждый шаг (1, 2, 3... 5)
2. Как сделать, чтоб стрелок (нажать вправо\влево) не было
3. Как установить шаг? я могу передвигать ролик в любое место(допустим 2.5 или 3.2) в `ScrollBar`, но я хотел бы, что он передвигался только между 1, 2, 3 ... 5

Как это сделать?

**P.S.** может мне нужно использовать совсем другое `View` вместо `ScrollBar`?

Comment: А почему `ScrollBar`? Он не для этого создан. Используйте `Slider`, задавайте с помощью `TickFrequency` нужное количество, стилизируйте если надо и все, вот вам готовое решение.

Comment: Чуть больше там надо сделать, а точнее - дописать `TickBar`. Вот [один из вариантов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4289864), вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3578214) код по сути тот же, но получился получше. При попытке провернуть у себя, говорило, что метод рисования устарел, [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45766452). Ну а [вот](http://vykrum.blogspot.com/2012/05/modified-wpf-slider-control.html) на всей этой основе человек написал другой вариант, с разделением на "уровни". В общем этого будет достаточно, что бы сделать свой вариант.